# Formula: Count text instance within table range

Tags: excel, count, excel-formula, instance

I want to find the instance of a text within a set range.

The following formula will work in general and produce the following info:

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B2;$B2)
```

Helper  Name
1  Bob
2  Bob
1   John
2   John
3   John

However, with this formula within a Table and insert data into a new row, you get this at the second instance of John:

```
   =COUNTIFS($B$2:$B6;$B5)
```

Help    Name
1   Bob
2   Bob
1   John
**3**   John
**3**   John
While the second instance of John should be:

```
   =COUNTIFS($B$2:$B5;$B5)
```

Since a table will automatically fill in the formula when adding another row, is there a different way to make this formula or an option to make this work?
Sadly, the following code won't work:

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B&Row(B5);$B5)
```

Thanks for any support!

Comment: @pnuts - While the **$** in `"B$2:B"` is a good reminder of what is being accomplished, strictly speaking it is not necessary as the text value will never increment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem with tables, new rows and auto-filled formulas that use conventional cell references. If you maintain the table method of cell addressing, you can reshape the *range* parameter of `COUNTIF` with `OFFSET` and use a table cell reference for the adjoining cell in the *Name* column.

[image]

The formula in the first *Helper* column cell below the header is,

`=COUNTIF(OFFSET([Name],0,0,ROW(1:1),1),[@Name])`

`OFFSET` is another *volatile* function (like `INDIRECT`) that recalculates on any calculation cycle; not just ones where the values that affect its outcome change. If you have a large amount of data, calculation lag will quickly become annoying.

More on this at [Use structured references in Excel table formulas](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/use-structured-references-in-excel-table-formulas-HA102749547.aspx)

Comment: Well played Jeeped.
Thank you very much for the answer and the link. Happy to start using new methods for formulas now too.